# How to destroy all tkinter toplevel window opened

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I have this few lines of code here which opens `tkinter toplevel window` which can be destroyed by clicking on the `destroy all button`. The challenge when i open several windows and i want to destroy all only one gets destroyed. Have tried the `quit` funtion but it close all the window including the the `root window`. I only want all the toplevel window to be destroyed.

```
import tkinter as tk




def open_window():
    global top1
    top1 = tk.Toplevel()

    top1.geometry("100x100")


def destroy_all():
    top1.destroy()



root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")


b1 = tk.Button(root, text="open", command=open_window)
b1.pack(side=tk.TOP)


b2 = tk.Button(root, text="destroy all", command=destroy_all)
b2.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you considered appending the windows to a list instead of a scalar variable?

Comment: @BryanOakley i don't understand what you suggesting.

Answer (score 5):

You could loop through all of the widgets you created, and destroy those that are `Toplevels`

```
def destroy_all():
    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        if isinstance(widget, tk.Toplevel):
            widget.destroy()
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to use list when dealing with dynamically generated widgets/containers. Here I would use a list to hold the Toplevel and then destroy each Toplevel in the list.

```
import tkinter as tk


def open_window():
    list_of_tops.append(tk.Toplevel(root))
    list_of_tops[-1].geometry("100x100")


def destroy_all():
    for top_window in list_of_tops:
        top_window.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
list_of_tops = [] # list to store any toplevel window.
tk.Button(root, text="open", command=open_window).pack(side=tk.TOP)
tk.Button(root, text="destroy all", command=destroy_all).pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
root.mainloop()
```